# Why can't I get the argument for my base function from the transformed function?

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the following transformed function as an example:

```
FirstCase[Hold[Sqrt[-3(x+1)]-4],Sqrt[x_]:>x,x,∞]
FirstCase[HoldForm[Sqrt[-3(x+1)]-4],Sqrt[x_]:>x,x,∞]
FirstCase[HoldComplete[Sqrt[-3(x+1)]-4],Sqrt[x_]:>x,x,∞]
FirstCase[Unevaluated[Sqrt[-3(x+1)]-4],Sqrt[x_]:>x,x,∞]
FirstCase[Defer[Sqrt[-3(x+1)]-4],Sqrt[x_]:>x,x,∞]
```

None of them are able to grab the correct argument of `Sqrt[...]` which is `-3(x+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Sqrt[x_]` gets nontrivially evaluated on the lhs of that rule—check `Sqrt[x_] // FullForm`. (Like `:=`, `:>` only prevents evaluation of its rhs, not its lhs.)

Instead, try using HoldPattern to prevent evaluation but maintain the same form for pattern matching:

```
FirstCase[Hold[Sqrt[-3 (x + 1)] - 4], HoldPattern[Sqrt[x_]] :> x, x, Infinity]
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice it as evaluating `Sqrt[x_]` still produced the nice typeset of `Sqrt`.